# Insert custom TypeConverter on a property at runtime, from inside a custom UITypeEditor

Tags: c#, runtime, typeconverter, uitypeeditor

I've created a custom UITypeEditor.

Can I possibly insert an attribute that also attaches a TypeConverter to my property from *inside* the UITypeEditor class?

I've tried the following, but nothing happens, no matter how I twist and turn it:

```
Attribute[] newAttributes = new Attribute[1];
newAttributes[0] = new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(BooleanConverter));
```

Now, the above needs to have the following attached to it somehow:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(context.Instance.PROPERTYNAME, newAttributes);
```

...but first of all I don't know how to get to the property in question in a generic way, and all code I try just fails. Even if I try to assign the TypeConverter in this manner globally, it fails. (Setting it as an attribute on the property itself works though, just to rule out that the bug is in that part.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeDescriptor` allows you to add attributes (at least, as far as `System.ComponentModel` is concerned) to *types* and *objects* - but not to specific properties. To do that (in a general way would require `TypeDescriptionProvider` - however, be advised that this is not a trivial thing to implement, and you need to write all of:

- the provider itself
- an `ICustomTypeDescriptor`
- a `PropertyDescriptor` for the things you want to manipulate

It is the `PropertyDescriptor` that would allow you to pretend you had additional attributes (or, via `override` change the `Converter` more directly, without messing with attributes).

Comment: Ah yeah, that explains it. And since I wanted to avoid recreating the PropertyDescriptor, I'll probably stick to having to use attributes the old way. Sounds like too much hassle to save a single line of code on a few properties. Thanks!