# XAML - Base64 ImageSource is not supported by Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, imagesource

I have to display SVG images in a WPF application. 
Trying not to use a 3rd party library i converted the SVG images manually ( via Inkscape ) to XAML.

My problem is now that the XAML files are not displayed correct.

If i view these XAML files in VisualStudio Designer i can see that there are some Images using a base64 string as "Source". The Designer shows the warning "File type not supported in Blend" on the "Source".

E.g.

```
  <Image xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="image4856" Source="data:image/png;base64,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" Width="27" Height="20">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform X="310" Y="279.5"/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
  </Image>
```

As mentioned, the XAML file is converted directly in a graphic design software ( Inkscape - SaveAs XAML ). Does VisualStudio support a base64 string as image source in XAML ?
Does anyone have a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16243638/1136211. Alternatively, put the base64 string into a resource (e.g. in `Window.Resources`) and bind to it with an IValueConverter that returns an ImageSource.

Comment: I would like to use the files as they are. In your example i would have to modify the XAML files.

Comment: You may perhaps replace the TypeConverter of the Image's Source property. Let me see...

Comment: Replacing the TypeConverter for the `ImageSource` class doesn't seem to work. Replacing it for the `Source` property [doesn't seem to be easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535715/1136211).

Comment: Another alternative would be a custom [MarkupExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/markup-extensions-for-xaml-overview).

Answer (score 0):

Since the Base64 string contains an encoded image buffer which can be decoded by one of WPF's BitmapDecoders and passed to the image object via MarkupExtension.

```
public class Base64Image : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Source)))
        {
            return BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }
    }
}
```

in Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{markupExtensions:Base64Image Source='...'}" Width="176.3889" Height="44.097225" Stretch="Fill"/>
```